# struct pack and crc in python

Tags: python, struct, crc

I am understanding a piece of code that computes the CRC for data that comes from a signal source. Following is the piece that I am not understanding. I see that python has a way to generate CRC function
I have initial seed of 0

```
application_crc_func = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x1F4ACFB13, initCrc=seed, rev=False)
```

so this should result in a function which takes the data on which I have to compute CRC as argument?
Below is the part of code I am not able to understand.

```
 # Use inverse of destination ID as the first value for 'data'
 data = struct.pack('>I', ((~dest_id) & mask32))
```

What does this do?

Answer (score 2):

The following code creates a packed binary data string. It's accomplished by using the [struct-module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

```
# Use inverse of destination ID as the first value for 'data'
data = struct.pack('>I', ((~dest_id) & mask32))
```

I'll break it down and try to explain what each operation does.

```
struct.pack('>I', ...)
```

The input is considered as a Big-endian, 32-bit (4 byte) unsigned integer.

```
(~dest_id) & mask32
```

There are two bitwise operators here, the `~` and `&`.

The `~` flips the bits of `dest_id`. It is often used when interpreting values in their [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form. This does the 'inverse' operation, mentioned in the comment.

The `&` does a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation which means that if a bit is set (the bit is `1`) in both numbers (`dest_id` and `mask32`), the resulting bit will be `1`. If either is `0`, then the resulting bit will be `0`. The operation in your context makes sure that the resulting value is not longer than 32 bits / 4 bytes.

You should read about [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and more specifically [how they work in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).